# How to create a multidimensional array from normal array

Tags: javascript, html, json, multidimensional-array

I have a json array after the form submission using formSerialize function like this

```
[
      {"name":"client_management-testmonitoring","value":"0"},
      {"name":"client_operations-testmonitoring","value":"0"},
      {"name":"tpl_management-testmonitoring","value":"0"},
      {"name":"tpl_operations-testmonitoring","value":"0"},
      {"name":"channel_partner-testmonitoring","value":"0"},
      {"name":"operator-testmonitoring","value":"0"},
      {"name":"financier-testmonitoring","value":"0"},
      {"name":"client_management-test_monitoring_2","value":"0"},
      {"name":"client_operations-test_monitoring_2","value":"0"},
      {"name":"tpl_management-test_monitoring_2","value":"0"},
      {"name":"tpl_operations-test_monitoring_2","value":"0"},
      {"name":"channel_partner-test_monitoring_2","value":"0"},
      {"name":"operator-test_monitoring_2","value":"0"},
      {"name":"financier-test_monitoring_2","value":"0"},
      {"name":"client_management-test_monitoring_3","value":"0"},
      {"name":"client_operations-test_monitoring_3","value":"0"},
      {"name":"tpl_management-test_monitoring_3","value":"0"},
      {"name":"tpl_operations-test_monitoring_3","value":"0"},
      {"name":"channel_partner-test_monitoring_3","value":"0"},
      {"name":"operator-test_monitoring_3","value":"0"},
      {"name":"financier-test_monitoring_3","value":"0"}
]
```

and i need to convert this array like this :

```
[
    {
        "role": [
            {
                "role_name": "client_management",
                "report_name": [
                    {
                        "test_monitoring_1": 1,
                        "test_monitoring_2": 1,
                        "test_monitoring_3": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "role": [
            {
                "role_name": "financier",
                "report_name": [
                    {
                        "test_monitoring_1": 1,
                        "test_monitoring_2": 0,
                        "test_monitoring_3": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

am trying this code to get the multidimesional array.

```
var formData = $('#' + reportType).serializeArray(),matrix_array =[];


for (var u = 0; u < formData.length; u++) {


    for (var user in formData[u])
    {
        if (user == 'name') {
            var matrix_name_n = formData[u][user],
                    matrix_name_a = matrix_name_n.split('-'),
                    role_name = matrix_name_a[0],
                    parameter_name = matrix_name_a[1];
            var matrix_array_2 = [];
        }
        if (user == 'value') {
            var matrix_param_value = formData[u][user], matrix_array_3 = [matrix_param_value];
        }

    }
    var matrix_array2 = {};
    var matrix_array2 = {};
    matrix_array2["role"] = role_name;
    matrix_array2[parameter_name] = matrix_param_value;

    matrix_array_2.push(matrix_array2);
    matrix_array.push(matrix_array_2);
    var insert_matrix = {};
    insert_matrix = JSON.stringify(formData);
}
```

but am not getting the expected result.Please help someone to sort out this issue

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: {
 "role" : [{ 
  role_name:"client_management",
  report_name:[{
   test_monitoring_1:1,
   test_monitoring_2:1,
   test_monitoring_3:0
  }] 
  }]
},
{
 "role" : [{ 
  role_name:"financier",
  report_name:[{
   test_monitoring_1:1,
   test_monitoring_2:0,
   test_monitoring_3:1
  }] 
  }]
}

Comment: Edit the question and add the result there. Properly format your question, it helps us figure out the problem @SoumyaSarasan

Comment: do you need the one behind the name, if a number is not given `test_monitoring_1:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the name by minus sign and use the first part as `role_name` and the second part as `report_name` property of the inner object.

```js
var data = [{ name: "client_management-testmonitoring", value: 0 }, { name: "client_operations-testmonitoring", value: 0 }, { name: "tpl_management-testmonitoring", value: 0 }, { name: "tpl_operations-testmonitoring", value: 0 }, { name: "channel_partner-testmonitoring", value: 0 }, { name: "operator-testmonitoring", value: 0 }, { name: "financier-testmonitoring", value: 0 }, { name: "client_management-test_monitoring_2", value: 0 }, { name: "client_operations-test_monitoring_2", value: 0 }, { name: "tpl_management-test_monitoring_2", value: 0 }, { name: "tpl_operations-test_monitoring_2", value: 0 }, { name: "channel_partner-test_monitoring_2", value: 0 }, { name: "operator-test_monitoring_2", value: 0 }, { name: "financier-test_monitoring_2", value: 0 }, { name: "client_management-test_monitoring_3", value: 0 }, { name: "client_operations-test_monitoring_3", value: 0 }, { name: "tpl_management-test_monitoring_3", value: 0 }, { name: "tpl_operations-test_monitoring_3", value: 0 }, { name: "channel_partner-test_monitoring_3", value: 0 }, { name: "operator-test_monitoring_3", value: 0 }, { name: "financier-test_monitoring_3", value: 0 }],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            var parts = a.name.split('-');
            if (!hash[parts[0]]) {
                hash[parts[0]] = {};
                r[0].role.push({ role_name: parts[0], report_name: [hash[parts[0]]] });
            }
            if (!parts[1].match(/\d$/)) {
                parts[1] = 'test_monitoring_1';
            }
            hash[parts[0]][parts[1]] = a.value;
            return r;
        }
    }(Object.create(null)), [{ report_name: "monitoring", role: [] }]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I need one more help. this array i need to insert to mongodb using node js. its not inserting correctly. $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/insert/" + id,
        dataType: "json",
        data: result,
        success: function(res) {
        }

    }); am using thihs code to insert

Comment: i have no idea of mongo and jquery.

Comment: you may have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and you could ask a new question about the problem with mongodb.

Comment: I need one more assistance

Comment: [{"report_name":"monitoring",
"role":[{"role_name":"client_management","parameter_name":[{"monitoring":"0","test_monitoring_2":"0","test_monitoring_3":"0"}]},
{"role_name":"client_operations","parameter_name":[{"monitoring":"0","test_monitoring_2":"0","test_monitoring_3":"0"}]}],
{"role_name":"operator","parameter_name":[{"monitoring":"0","test_monitoring_2":"0","test_monitoring_3":"0"}]},
":[{"role_name":"financier","parameter_name":[{"monitoring":"0","test_monitoring_2":"0","test_monitoring_3":"0"}]}]}] i need an array like this.

Comment: its working. but need some more re arrangement like above mentioned array